# Jquery Mobile Multi-Page Site with Widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

My multi-page jQuery Mobile site works well, except when an individual page is re-loaded with the refresh button on the browser. I understand that the AJAX is only loading the content in the data-role="page" div, but that renders widgets like popups useless.

What I am looking for is a way to re-style, re-load, re-initialize, or re-something the widgets so that they work even after someone mistakenly refreshes the browser. Because the widgets may vary on a per-page basis, I need a general way to apply all the jQuery styles and widget functions. I have tried the following inside the page div:

```
$( document ).delegate("#toc", "pageinit", function() {
    $("#toc").trigger('create')
});
```

As well as many variations of that code to no avail. Do I need to re-load the entire jQuery Mobile code in each page div? Or is there a much simpler method that I am missing? Splitting the pages into separate html files is very undesirable for this project.

Comment: You mean _single page model_, each page in a separate html file. For each place js libraries and CSS in head tag, when a user refreshes pageX.html, it will render with no issues.

Comment: That's the problem. I want to avoid separate html pages like the plague.

Comment: Then use a _multi-page model_, all pages in one file. Which version are you using?

Comment: That is what I am using, but if the user refreshes the browser jQuery widgets don't work anymore. I would like to correct that, if possible, without going to the single page model.

Comment: Hmmm..I'm not sure if `$.mobile.initializePage();` would work. I have to try it.

Comment: Are you using latest version of JQM?

Comment: Yes, 1.4, the latest stable version.

Comment: If you're using external widgets, such as panel, toolbar, popup, you need to initialize them manually anyway. `$(function() { $("[data-role=popup]").popup();`.

Comment: They are initialized when the user opens the page initially. I tried your code suggestion but it still doesn't work after a refresh.

Comment: Can you post a sample code of any page other than the initial/ first one?

Comment: I just tested it, its working on refresh. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/xX9Eg/show/

Comment: Thanks for your help. There must be something else in my code that's causing problems for me.